# Parallelize for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a transformer that's processing a dataframe by checking for presence of certain strings in a few columns:

```
class GenerateTextFlags(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, variables=None):
        if not isinstance(variables, list):
            self.variables = sorted([variables])
        else:
            self.variables = sorted(variables)
        
        self.address_list = ['address', 'adres', 'adress', 'adresse', 'anschrift']
        
        self.contact_list = ['contact information', 'contactgegevens', 'contactinfo']
        
        self.cc_list = ['credit card', 'creditcard', 'bank card']


    def text_cleanup(self, input_str):
        from unidecode import unidecode
        import string
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        from html import unescape
        s = BeautifulSoup(unescape(input_str), 'lxml').text
        cleaner = r'<.*?>|-|#x20;|[ \t]{2,}' # clean html
        s = re.sub(cleaner, '', str(s))
        s = unidecode(s)
        s = s.lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
        return s
    

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        import time
        print("Processing GenerateTextFlags")
        X = X[self.variables].fillna(" ").replace('nan', " ").copy()
        
        for col in self.variables:

            print('Processing: '+col+'; started at', round(time.time()/60)%1000, 'minutes')
            
            X[col] = X[col].apply(self.text_cleanup)
            X[col+'_CONTAINS_ADDRESS'] = X[col].str.contains('|'.join(self.address_list))*1
            X[col+'_CONTAINS_CONTACTINFO'] = X[col].str.contains('|'.join(self.contact_list))*1
            X[col+'_CONTAINS_BANKINGINFO'] = X[col].str.contains('|'.join(self.cc_list))*1
            
        
        X = X.drop(self.variables, axis=1)
        print('Finished processing at:', round(time.time()/60)%1000, 'minutes')
        
        return X
```

What have I above is a toned-down sample. The actual code contains ~10 lists with ~25 elements each and I'm checking ~5 text columns to see if they contain any of the elements in that list and saving it to a flag.

As you can see, processing each individual column is independent and can be run in parallel. I'm just not sure how to do it. I'm running this transformer on over a million rows and it's taking a very long time to finish (I'm using an M5 EC2 instance with 16 cores and 64 GB RAM, so resource-wise I think I'm fine, just need to optimize my code to utilize all the resources efficiently).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to group columns and use `applymap` on them:

```
cols = self.variables
contains_address = [y + '_CONTAINS_ADDRESS' for y in cols]

X[cols] = X[cols].applymap(self.text_cleanup)
X[contains_address] = X[cols].applymap(lambda y: 
y*1 if '|'.join(self.address_list) in y else y)
....
```

You can also use the [pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel) package that can improve the performance:

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()

X[cols] = X[cols].parallel_applymap(self.text_cleanup)
X[contains_address] = X[cols].parallel_applymap(lambda y: 
y*1 if '|'.join(self.address_list) in y else y)
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip Michael, I tried to test this logic and I'm getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
--> X[contains_address] = X[self.variables].applymap(lambda y: y.str.contains('|'.join(self.address_list))*1) .

I tried taking the 'str' out and now I'm getting the same error but with - 'str' object has no attribute 'contains' - instead. Thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: Nevermind, this fixed it:

X[contains_address] = X[self.variables].apply(lambda y: y.str.contains('|'.join(self.address_list))*1)

Comment: Are you sure that it is doing what it should do? Because "apply" should do  it only once, I have another solution, but please check if it is working as intended/

Comment: I'm still testing it but the speed hasn't really improved. Can you show me the other solution you were thinking of?

Comment: Thanks Michael, pandarallel totally upped the performance. I'm seeing close to 80% reduction in processing time.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to profile your code, but it seems like the part that takes the most time is effectively this (defactored a bit by expanding the code of `text_cleanup()` at its call site):

```
    for col in self.variables:
        for input_str in X[col]:
            from unidecode import unidecode
            import string
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
            from html import unescape
            s = BeautifulSoup(unescape(input_str), 'lxml').text
            cleaner = r'<.*?>|-|#x20;|[ \t]{2,}' # clean html
            s = re.sub(cleaner, '', str(s))
            s = unidecode(s)
            s = s.lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

This is a nested for loop operating on every cell of the DataFrame.  That's dead slow of course, but more than that, why does it call `import` on every cell?  That's pure overhead, hoist those statements to the top of the file!

Next, you're using a regex to strip some characters, and at the end you remove all punctuation.  You could move the punctuation removal into the regex I would think.  And of course you should not call `maketrans()` every time through the loop, but just once at the top.

Get these basics right first, then profile.  See which of those many string transformation functions takes the most time.

If you really want to speed this up by a factor of 100 or so, you should write your transform in C, C++, Numba, or some other compiled language, and run it on the entire array at once (i.e. run the nested loops in compiled code).  That will be more effective than throwing threads at the problem.